# Creating Multi-Paged PDFs from Adobe Photoshop exports

Tags: pdf, photoshop

I have multiple A4 Pages I created and exported with Photoshop and need them to be in one PDF.

I also need

- The software to be free (not necessarily as in GNU/Free, I just don't want to pay for it)
- To insert Hyperlinks
- The text to remain as real text, not rendered pixels
- To embed the font I used so it doesn't disappear when looked at on other machines
- The software to run on Windows 10
  So far, I've tried LibreOffice but it just kinda froze when trying to open the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ghostscript? It handles PDF input and output (and many other formats,) and there is probably a user friendly GUI available for your platform (which you didn't mention which makes recommendations a bit difficult).

I don't know about hyperlinks, though.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. I'm running windows 10. I'll check out some GUIs, I found GSview so far. Any other you'd recommend?

Comment: GSView is probably centered on presentation, I don't know whether it supports file processing. My guess is that your safest bet is to use the command line interface. As this sounds like a one-off task, writing a batch file would probably be overkill.

Comment: Searching on Stack Overflow, I found a reference to `PDFsam` which might be even more suitable for your case. The mobile SO application doesn't let me copy a link to that question, though, so you need to search yourself.